# Powershell script fails to get environment variable

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am using a PS script in my TFS server as a build step.  On the TFS server, I have set a system environment variable for a path.  If I RDP into the server, I can correctly get the path from PS.  However, the script only gets an empty string.  I am an admin on the machine.  Is there a reason why the local service account cannot see the environment variable?

Comment: Get the environment of the LOCAL SYSTEM account and see if your variable is defined.

Comment: What does "I have set a system environment variable for a path" mean? What does "the script only gets an empty string" mean? (Remember, nobody can see your screen!) You need to put more information in your question.

Comment: What is "the environment variable"?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I'm not sure what is unclear to you.  I created a system-level environment variable that contains a path.  When I try to retrieve the path in the script, an empty string is returned.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I don't understand your question.  The name of the variable doesn't matter, does it?  It's just a variable that is meant to hold a path.

Comment: How are you setting the environment variable?  Processes don't share environments.

Comment: HOW are you retrieving the path in the script? What does the code look like? You are best served by putting ALL relevant details into your question. (You are asking for help, after all. Help us help you.)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 It's set via the advanced system settings console in windows.  I can see the variable and value in the registry as well under HKLM.

Comment: How are you referencing that in powershell?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I'm using  $env:MyVariable to access it.  I understand I'm asking for help, but expecting perfectly detailed questions is somewhat silly.  The entire point of this is that I am not very familiar with this and thus may not know what is and is not "relevant" to this situation.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'm grabbing it with  $env:MyVairable.  If I do a dir env: in the script, the variable is listed but the value is empty.

Comment: Insufficient information in the question. If you don't want to provide the needed detail, that's up to you, of course, but you are only hindering others from assisting. I will bow out at this point...

Comment: Did you restart your build agent **after** you set the environment variable? If you set the environment variable outside the agent process, you need to restart the process before it's visible.

Comment: @DanielMann That was it... a simple restart fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Needed to restart the system since the variable was set outside of the service/process.